# Compare and Remove duplicate part of string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a an array of product names like:

- Big Bottle 500ml
- Big Bottle 1l
- Big Bottle 2l

I want to remove the duplicated first part of the string in JavaScript to produce an array like:

- 500ml
- 1l
- 2l

The Product names can be anything i.e. Tub 8oz but will always have duplication/the same prefix at the start

Not sure where to start with this regex or maybe a loop that compares each character until it hits a missmatch

Comment: What have you tried? How about providing a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I did not down vote you.

Comment: Will all the strings have the same prefix (i.e. the same product name), or does the array contain multiple different product names? Maybe you could use some variation of a Trie where the leaves only store the remainder of the strings. Then you just need to iterate over the leaves. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Answer (score 1):

If your format will always be `Name Name Name ... XXXunit`. You can easily split the string with the space delimiter. It doesn't really detect any duplicates, but based on your post, it sounds like youre just trynna get the value and unit

```js
const data = ['Tub 500ml', 'Tub 450ml', 'Small Can 200ml', 'Big Ass Bottle 999ml', 'Artificial Rain Tank V99.55 5500.50L'];
const result = [];

data.forEach(function(item){
  const splitted = item.split(" ");
  result.push(splitted[splitted.length - 1]);
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you said `but will always have duplication at the start` so you can try following

Get the string to remove from the first element and then loop through all the elements to remove that string

```js
let arr1 = ['Big Bottle 500ml', 'Big Bottle 1l', 'Big Bottle 2l']

let arr2 = ['Bottle 500ml', 'Bottle 1l', 'Bottle 2l']

function getData(arr) {
  let strToRemove = arr[0].match(/\D+/)[0]

  return arr.map(d => d.replace(strToRemove, '').trim())
}

console.log(getData(arr1))

console.log(getData(arr2))
```

Comment: What about products with numbers in name?

Answer (score 1):

Using `Array#reduce()` to walk through all the  characters to find the common starting string then `map()` to remove it

```js
const prods = ['Big Bottle 500ml','Big Bottle 1l','Big Bottle 2l'];

const dupStr = [...prods[0]].reduce((a, c) => {
  return prods.every(s => s.startsWith(a + c)) ? a + c : a;
}, '')

const res = prods.map(s => s.replace(dupStr, '').trim())

console.log(`common string :: "${dupStr}"`)
console.log('results ::\n',res)
```

Comment: Yes this seems to work the best, as it handles numbers in the prefix

Comment: If it helped feel free to accept answer